# i want to add product in cart but i got ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, django-views

I'm new to Python django, I'm trying to make e-commerce website but when I clicked the cart button then I have seen in the console 500 Internal Server Error) and terminal show  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' Please anyone can help I want to display product item on the cart page, Please anyone can help

```py
def addtocart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
            product_check = Product.objects.get(id=prod_id)
            if (product_check):
                if(Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, product_id=prod_id)):
                    return JsonResponse({'status': "product alredy in cart"})
                else:
                    prod_qty = int(request.POST.get('product_qty'))
                    if product_check.quantity >= prod_qty :
                        Cart.objects.create(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id, product_qty=prod_qty)
                        return JsonResponse({'status': "Product added successfully."})
                    else:
                        return JsonResponse({'status': "Only"+ str(product_check.quantity) +" quantity available"})

            else:
                return JsonResponse({'status': "no such product found"})
            
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': "Login to Continue"})
        
    return redirect('/')`
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
 $('.increment-btn').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var inc_value = $(this).closest ('.product_data').find('.qty-input').val();
  var value = parseInt(inc_value,10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  if(value < 10)

  {
    value++;
    $(this).closest ('.product_data').find('.qty-input').val(value);
 
  }

 });
 $('.decrement-btn').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var dec_value = $(this).closest ('.product_data').find('.qty-input').val();
  var value = parseInt(dec_value,10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  if(value > 1)

  {
    value--;
    $(this).closest ('.product_data').find('.qty-input').val(value);
 
  }


});
 // for ad to cart
 $('.addToCartBtn').click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val();
  var product_qty = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.qty-input').val();
  var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
  
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/add-to-cart/",
    data: {
      'product_id': product_id,
      'product_qty': product_qty,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: token

    },
    success: function (response){
      console.log(response)
      alertify.success(response.status)

    }


  });

 });
// for ad to cart end
});
```

Comment: `request.POST.get('product_id')` is probably not a valid int, print it and see what you get.

Comment: wel it seems empty...